# React Native 0.73 Android application containing imported libraries fails to build using Gradle Plugin v.8

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I run a React Native project which uses third party libraries like `react-native-biometrics`, `react-native-blob-utils` and many more.
I am trying to upgrade `react-native` library from 0.72 to 0.73. Version 0.73 depends on Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version 8. AGP v.8 requires that my application should define package name not in `AndroidManifest.xml` file (`package` attribute in `application` tag) but in `android/build.gradle` as `android { namespace: 'com.example' }`.

Moreover, all included third party libraries should also follow this "namespace" rule, but very many of them still didn't get an update setting namespace instead of package name, and it is not sure if some of them will ever get. That's why I'm getting an error during building process.

```
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
```

More details on "the rule" available here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/671

My question is if there is a solution which would let me use `react-native` v. 0.73 + AGP v.8 and third part libraries not satisfying mentioned rule i.e.: namespace not defined in `android/build.gradle` but in `AndroidManifest.xml` as `package` attribute for `application` tag?